# Global dict, not all threads adding keys to it?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am confused about global variables in Python. Sometimes a global variable is shared among all instances of my program and sometimes an instance will create its own version of the global variable.

What I need is to have one handler that handles items put into a global dictionary. There is only one function that adds items to the global dictionary, but this function is run multiple times concurrently.

In views:

```
global_dict = {}

def handler():
    global global_dict 

    print "Starting handler"
    while True:
        local_dict = dict(global_dict) 
        for key, v in local_dict.iteritems():
            handle_the_item(v)
            del global_dict[key]
            print "Handled: ", key
        time.sleep(0.05)

def some_function(function_number)
    global global_dict

    print "Starting function", function_number
    for x in y:
        key = random.randint(0, 5000000)
        print function_number, "giving to handler:", key
        global_dict[key] = some_item
```

I start:

(I use Django so each function is started by calling a url with some parameter)

```
handler()
some_function(1)
some_function(2)
some_function(3)
```

It prints:

```
Starting handler
Starting function 1
Starting function 2
Starting function 3

1 giving to handler 111111
2 giving to handler 222222
3 giving to handler 333333
1 giving to handler 444444
2 giving to handler 555555
3 giving to handler 666666

Handled: 111111
Handled: 222222
Handled: 444444
Handled: 555555
```

The handler never handles the items added by function 3. As far as I can tell, this is because the handler and function 3 each have their own instances of the (supposedly) global variable global_dict. I also verified this by printing out the length of global_dict in some_function(). global_dict in function 3 keeps growing as more items are added.

Note that it is random which functions share an instance of global_dict and which have their own. If I stop everything and run it again, it may be that all instances share global_dict. Or none. Or 3 and 1 along with the handler.

Comment: I noticed that you don't check for `key` in `global_dict`. It is possible that Python's random number generator is the cause of your problems and that you are overwriting keys already in `global_dict`.

Comment: Had the same thought and checked that. I print out the key number that I am giving to the handler and they are different (and more random than my easier-to-read example numbers here).

Comment: Your `some_function` definition is missing a semicolon. Is this your actual code?

Comment: You have so many race conditions I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I just wrote a long post explaining exactly why this happens. You may want to [check it out here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Comment: No, it is a simplification to illustrate my issue. But very close to what the code is.

Comment: @Kevin I think you mean 'colon'

Comment: btw, you do not need to mark `global_dict` as global, as long as you no not need to put a new dict into the variable. It is a container.

Comment: How are you invoking Django? If you are running it in mod_python for example then Apache will start multiple processes and those processes cannot share global variables but each process may handle multiple requests.

Comment: A programmer had a problem. He thought "I know, I’ll solve it with threads!". has Now problems. two he

Comment: @Duncan, I am running it using Webfaction. I guess I don't know what they use. It is Apache. Are you saying that whether the functions share the global variable depends on whether they were called by different processes or by the same process?

Comment: Why I am using threads in the first place: I am doing scraping and most of the time is spent waiting for the url. So it makes sense to run multiple functions at the same time.

Comment: @user984003: Yes, a WSGI request is not guaranteed to be handled in the same process. It could be that you are looking at *multiple processes instead* here.

Comment: I see. What if I only call the function once and then this function starts multiple threads? Then they should all share the global variable, no?

Comment: If someone wants to write up the answer then I'll mark it as correct. I'm sure the issue was because multiple processes were started. I'm now doing it using regular threads: thread.start_new_thread(some_function(), (1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an application such as Django behind a web server the web server will usually run multiple instances of your application as separate long processes. If several requests come in together they will be distributed across the application processes.

This means that you cannot depend on global variables being shared across requests. You might be lucky and the requests come in to the same process, or you might be unlucky and different requests go to different instances of the application.

If you need to share state between web requests then you should use some other mechanism such as a database or memcached.